# Problems Renaming Fields with Make Feature Layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I am using Make Feature Layer as a tool in a model. You can see I have two instances of the tool. I'm having issues with the top one, Make Feature Layer (2).

[image: ModelBuilder Diagram]

I am using the tool's field renaming feature in order to avoid the complicated Add Field, Calculate Field, Delete Field process that is the other option for renaming. However, the tool is not seeing the correct field map from the input layer. It is unaware of the two required fields Shape_Length and Shape_Area. Therefore, when these two fields unexpectedly show up, the renaming is all offset by two fields. For instance, here is a table showing an example of my settings and desired result compared to my actual result.

[image: example results table]

Now to form this into some kind of question. Has anyone else experienced this? How can I get the tool to see the correct field map? Or is there another way around this?

Comment: If you are on 10.2 +, consider using the Alter Field GP tool instead if you can't get Make Feature Layer working.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on 10.1

Comment: Make Feature Layer cannot actually rename a field, it can only rename the alias.  This approach just won't work in any version of ArcMap. Feature Class to Feature Class and Table to Table can actually rename fields when you output to a new feature class or table, and it is fast.  However, if you do not create a new feature class only the Add Field, Calculate Field, Delete Field option is available at 10.1.  You don't need the Make Feature Layer step and can directly use the FC to FC tool in your model to do the field renaming.

Comment: Wow I never saw that I can rename fields if I right-click field names in Feature Class to Feature Class' field map. I'm going to try this to see if it works. If it does, can you post the comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Feature Class to Feature Class is still seeing what looks like an outdated version of the field map. In the actual field map, some fields are slightly out of order. I will go ahead with the tool and see what happens when I rename the fields.

Comment: The field order cannot be altered by the FC to FC tool.  Fields can be dropped by the tool, but not reordered.  New fields can also be added using the FC to FC tool, but the new fields are always appended at the end of the FC and the names of the new fields cannot already exist in the original FC.

Comment: What I am wondering is: Say Field A is the Column 1 of the input table, and I use FC to FC to rename it Field B. But, the FC to FC tool thinks Field A is in the Column 2. Will the tool find Field A and rename it Field B, or will it just name whatever happens to be in Column 1?

Comment: Your question is confusing and seems to reflect a peculiarity of the way you are using Model Builder.  The Parameters of the model are probably not going to refresh without actually running the model with the parameters assigned.  So I have no way to predict how your model will behave with all possible parameter assignments.  The FC to FC field map is not that flexible and will likely fail or produce unexpected results if the parameters constantly change the FC to FC input schema.  If that is happening, you need to convert to Python and write some complex code to handle each schema correctly.

Comment: I ran it again after implementing your solution, which worked. The field map is now corrected, so I'm wondering if the field map in FC to FC was just out of sync because of some edits I made upstream. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Feature Layer cannot actually rename a field, it can only rename the alias (although even that fails if the tool generates a layer directly in ArcMap outside of a model). This approach just won't work in any version of ArcMap.

Feature Class to Feature Class and Table to Table can actually rename fields when you output to a new feature class or table, and it is fast. Additionally, you can convert field types, modify Text field lengths, etc. with these two tools when you create a new FC/table as long as all of the data contained in the field is fully compatible with the field modification.  Unfortunately, these tools cannot be used to change the field order of the original FC/table in the output.

However, if you do not create a new feature class/table only the Add Field, Calculate Field, Delete Field option is available at 10.1. The Alter Field GP tool is only available at 10.2+.

You don't need the Make Feature Layer step and can directly use the FC to FC tool in your model to do the field renaming.